# Issues when upgrading and dockerising a Postgres v9.2 legacy database using pg_dumpall and pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am using an official postgres v12 docker image that I want to initialise with two SQL dump files that are gathered from a remote legacy v9.2 postgres server during the docker build phase:

```
RUN ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST "pg_dumpall -w -U $REMOTE_DB_USER -h localhost -p $REMOTE_DB_PORT --clean --globals-only -l $REMOTE_DB_NAME" >> dump/a_globals.sql

RUN ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST "pg_dump -w -U $REMOTE_DB_USER -h localhost -p $REMOTE_DB_PORT --clean --create $REMOTE_DB_NAME" >> dump/b_db.sql
```

By placing both `a_globals.sql` and `b_db.sql` files into the docker image folder `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, then the database is initialised with the legacy SQL files when the v12 container starts (as described [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)). Docker is working correctly, the dump files are retrieved successfully. However I am running into problems initialising the container's database and require guidance:

1. When the container starts to initialise its DB, it stops with `ERROR:  role $someDBRole does not exist`. This is because the psql v9.2 dump SQL files `DROP` roles before reinstating them; the container DB does not like this. Unfortunately it is not until psql v9.4 that `pg_dumpall` and `pg_dump` have the option to `--if-exists` (see pg_dumpall [v9.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pg-dumpall.html) documentation). What would you suggest that I do in order to remedy this? I could manually edit the SQL dump files, but this would be impractical as the snapshots of the legacy DB need to be automated. Is there a way to suppress this error during container startup?
2. If I want to convert from ASCII to UTF-8, is it adequate to simply set the encoding option for `pg_dumpall` and `pg_dump`? Or do I need to take into consideration other issues when upgrading?
3. Is there a way to supress the removal and adding of the postgres super user which is in the dump SQL?
4. In general are there any other gotchas when containerising and/or updating a postgres DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Docker so I don't know how straightforward it'll be do to these things, but in general, pg_dump/dumpall output, when it's in SQL format, will work just fine after having gone through some ugly string manipulation.

1. Pipe it through `sed -e 's/DROP ROLE/DROP ROLE IF EXISTS/'`, ideally when writing the `.sql`s, but it's fine to just run `sed -i -e <...>` to munge the files in-place after they're created if you don't have a full shell available. Make it `sed -r -e '/^DROP ROLE/DROP ROLE IF EXISTS/` if you're worried about strings containing `DROP ROLE` in your data, at the cost of portability (AFAIK `-r` is a GNU addition to sed).
2. Yes. It's worth checking the data in pg12 to make sure it got imported correctly, but in the general case, pg_dump has been aware of encoding considerations since time immemorial, and a dump->load is [absolutely the best way to change your DB encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809872/16361).
3. Sure. Find the lines that do it in your .sql, copy enough of it to be unique, and pipe it through `grep -v <what you copied>` :D
4. I can't speak to the containerizing aspect of things, but - and this is more of a general practice, not even really PG-specific - if you're dealing with a large DB that's getting migrated, prepare a small one, as similar as possible to the real one but omitting any bulky data, to test with to get everything working so that doing the real migration is just a matter of changing some vars (I guess `$REMOtE_HOST` and `$REMOTE_PORT` in your case). If it's not large, then just be comfortable blowing away any pg12 containers that failed partway through the import, figure out & do whatever to fix the failure, and start from the top again until it works end-to-end.